# Clojure- How would you pull weather data from a link and then work out the warmest day of each calendar month

Tags: clojure

So I was surfing through practice problems on 4clojure.com and there has been one problem that I cannot seem to work out, bare in mind clojure is pretty new to me. The question is work out the warmest day of each calendar month from a link they provided? This is one of the hardest questions I've come across online and I genuinely have clue on how to solve this. https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/hadobs/hadcet/cetdl1772on.dat), that is the link they provided alongside this side information of the format of the file. "the format of the file is Column 1: year, Column 2: day, Columns 3-14:daily CET values expressed in
tenths of a degree. There are 12 columns; one for each of the 12 months". Been trying for an hour and have made zero progress, it's stressing me out as this is the first time I've struggled with an online practice question :/

Comment: I believe you can use `slurp` on a web page.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is on 4clojure? I don't think there are any problems there that require I/O, and Google search seems to agree: there are no hits for the problem you describe on site:4clojure.com.

Comment: Yes I'm sure and Slurp? I'll have a look into that

Comment: @Demonx - which problem is that at 4Clojure? A link would be nice. :-)

Comment: For those who, like me, had their interest piqued by this question - while I cannot find anything like this at 4clojure, I did find [this page at amazonaws.com](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/2117_19f0a65e216747f38f13c5318ce546de.html) where the author is interested in processing data from the Met Office in R. Of course, nothing stops someone from doing similar processing in God's Own Language. (Yes, of *course* I meant Aramaic - what else could I possibly have meant? :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Outline:

- use `slurp` on the url to get a gigantic string
- use `str/split-lines` to get each line
- use `str/split` to get each field of each line
- use Java interop `Integer/parseInt` to convert "123" -> 123 for each field
- etc

Please see the list of documentation in the README of [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).

Especially study the Clojure CheatSheet, plus books like Brave Clojure and Getting Clojure.

Comment: Thankyou, Now I know how I'll structure it and work methodically thankyou